# Can TFS 2012 perform merges across projects in the same collection?

Tags: version-control, tfs

Is it possible to merge changes across projects in TFS 2012?  If so, it doesn't seem obvious to me how.  I find myself needing to do this because we created a new project when we really should have created a branch (or reorganized our branches).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use baseless merging from within the IDE (select merge) or using the TF command line utility. The following image shows a merge from team project Area 52 to team project Area 51, where no branch relationship exists. The IDE correctly identifies the merge as a baseless merge:
[image: baseless merge image]

Caution is advised though and I recommend you read the section on baseless merging in the Branching Guide (http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) first.

I did  quick test and documented the findings here in a rough format: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2012/12/13/faq-branching-is-easy-but-can-i-merge-without-branching.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you have a couple of options. If the code is distinct e.g. you have something like this.

`$/TeamProject1/Main/Source/Solution1`

`$/TeamProject2/Main/Source/Solution2`

And you want to branch solution 1 across to team project 2 then you can just use the "branch" functionality in the Visual Studio UI. Put the appropriate path in the "target" textbox and you should be good.

If you have the same code in 2 separate team projects then you will need to do a baseless merge. e.g.

`$/TeamProject1/Main/Source/Solution1`

`$/TeamProject2/Main/Source/Solution1`

Open up a Visual Studio command prompt and navigate to your TFS workspace, then use the following command

`tf merge $/TeamProject1/Main/Source/Solution1 $/TeamProject2/Main/Source/Solution1 /baseless /recursive`

This will merge the 2 versions of solution 1. Be aware though that you may get problems if files have been renamed or deleted. TFS will also probably treat each file as a merge conflict (unless the content is identical) and you will manually need to decide which files (Source or Target) to overwrite / merge.

Once the baseless merge has been checked in then a merge relationship will be created and any further merges will be able to be done from the IDE.